# How To Write Java Lambda function To Call The Class That The Maven Gatling plugin is Ultimately Calling and Run in AWS LAMBDA

Tags: java, scala, maven, gatling, scala-gatling

I execute perf tests using below maven command,

**mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=simulations.Stageabcsite**

Now my need is  i would like to use a Java Lambda function instead of mvn because i have a requirement to run this gatling code on AWS lambda

Here is my pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/
    2001/.   
  XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/. 
    xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.sre</groupId>
<artifactId>SRE</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.1</version>


   <properties>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <gatling.version>${project.version}</gatling.version>
   <gatling-plugin.version>3.0.3</gatling-plugin.version>
  <scala-maven-plugin.version>4.2.0</scala-maven-plugin.version>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
   <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
     <version>${gatling.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
     <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
     <version>2.4.0</version>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
     <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
     <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
     <version>2.9.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
     <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

     <build>
     <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>

     <plugins>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>${scala-maven-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
            <goals>
            <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
             <configuration>
            <jvmArgs>
            <jvmArg>-Xss100M</jvmArg>
            </jvmArgs>
            <args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
            <arg>-feature</arg>
            <arg>-unchecked</arg>
            <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
            <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
            </args>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
         <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
        <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${gatling-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
        <testResources>
         <testResource>
             <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
      </testResources>
        </build>
            </project>
```

Here is the gatling code which Java Lambda function should be calling

```
     package simulations


import baseConfig.BaseSimulation

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.http.Predef._
import io.gatling.jdbc.Predef._

class Stageabcsite extends BaseSimulation {



val headers_0 = Map(
    "accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control" -> "max-age=0",
    "content-type" -> "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarygecOpCycXAuBFkiL",
    "origin" -> "https://admin-stage.abc.xyz.com",
    "sec-fetch-mode" -> "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site" -> "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user" -> "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests" -> "1")

val headers_currentrevision = Map(
    "accept" -> "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "cache-control" -> "max-age=0",
    "referer" -> "https://admin-stage.abc.xyz.com/en/node/add/big-page",
    "sec-fetch-mode" -> "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site" -> "same-origin",
    "sec-fetch-user" -> "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests" -> "1")

val headers_Bigcontent = Map(
    "accept" -> "*/*",
    "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "referer" -> "https://admin-stage.abc.xyz.com/en/content/test-drupal-content-0",
    "sec-fetch-mode" -> "no-cors",
    "sec-fetch-site" -> "cross-site")

val headers_testDrupalContentAfterSaving = Map(
    "accept" -> "*/*",
    "accept-encoding" -> "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language" -> "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "if-modified-since" -> "Tue, 18 Feb 2020 18:00:00 GMT",
    "referer" -> "https://admin-stage.abc.xyz.com/en/content/test-drupal-content-0",
    "sec-fetch-mode" -> "no-cors",
    "sec-fetch-site" -> "cross-site")


val scn = scenario("Stage abc Site Baseline")

    .exec(http("Log In")
        .post("/en/fiveprime3primewbc")
        .headers(headers_fiveprime)
        .formParam("name", "ab_aryan")
        .formParam("pass", "dragon3")
        .formParam("form_build_id", "form-KU0StakJoFB8ijbpmBm8Jfsc11lzVrZPJ4LBlJ233QI")
        .formParam("form_id", "user_login")
        .formParam("op", "Log in")
        .check(status.is(302))
        .check(bodyString.saveAs("Login_Response")))

    .exec(http("Add Big Page Save Content")
        .post("/en/node/add/big-page")
        .headers(headers_0)
        .body(RawFileBody("/Users/dast/Downloads/abcwebsitetests-CQ-1159-Self-Service-Perf-To-Use-Maven/src/test/resources/data/0000_request.dat"))

    )

    .exec(http("Current Revision")
        .get("/en/node/1496326/current-revision")
        .headers(headers_currentrevision)
        .check(status.is(302)))
    .pause(1)

    .exec(http("After Saving View Youtube Iframe")
        .get(uri2 + "/iframe_api")
        .headers(headers_Bigcontent))
    .exec(http("After Saving View Draft Content ")
        .get(uri5 + "?id=DC-9597311")
        .headers(headers_testDrupalContentAfterSaving))

setUp(

    scn.inject(
        constantConcurrentUsers(800) during(60))
        .protocols(httpProtocol))


    .maxDuration(60)
    }
```